# find_element_by_id() when it doesn't find any element

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop, cycle

I've just started learning python and I'm using selenium to interact with the web pages.
I have to repeat a specific action until a certain element is present in the HTML code, so I wrote something like this:
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
 t = driver.find_element_by_id("i3") 
 t.send_keys(Codice)

 while driver.find_element_by_id("i3")==t:

   time.sleep(5)

   t.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

But it doesn't work because it doesn' stop at the end so I wanted to know what does the function driver.find_element_by_id("i3") returns when it doesn't find the element.
Also, is there a more appropriate cycle for doing this?
Thank you and sorry for the bad english

Comment: Your intentions are not quite clear. Tell us what is your goal (manual actions sequence/pseudocode)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unclear, what I can say here is the `while` loop to validate the element is presented can be done by

```
while driver.find_elements_by_id("i3")
```

Since `driver.find_elements_by_id` return list of web elements. In case elements found list in not empty and true, in case no elements found the list is empty and is false.

Comment: list has no method `len`. did you mean `len(driver.find_elements_by_id("i3"))`? Also you don't need any comparison of list length with `0` - simple `while driver.find_elements_by_id("i3")` should be enough

Comment: @JaSON Thanks! You are right. I didn't code python for a long time :) Using Java for the last 5 years :)